# How to move a circular image(png) using touch in android depending upon the touch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

i want to rotate an image(png) in android depending upon the intensity of touch.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class GetmouseActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new Panel(this));
}

public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private ViewThread mThread;

    private int mX;
    private int mY;

    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mThread = new ViewThread(this);
    }

    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(25);
        for (int y = 30, alpha = 255; alpha > 2; alpha >>= 1, y += 10) {
            paint.setAlpha(alpha);

            canvas.drawLine(0, y, 100, y, paint);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mX, mY, null);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (!mThread.isAlive()) {
            mThread = new ViewThread(this);
            mThread.setRunning(true);
            mThread.start();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mThread.isAlive()) {
            mThread.setRunning(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mX = (int) event.getX() - mBitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        mY = (int) event.getY() - mBitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}

public class ViewThread extends Thread {
    private Panel mPanel;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    public ViewThread(Panel panel) {
        mPanel = panel;
        mHolder = mPanel.getHolder();
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        mRun = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        while (mRun) {
            canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                mPanel.doDraw(canvas);
                mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
  }
```

try this